# How to clear previous data in console C#?

Tags: c#, stack, console-application

I'd appreciate if someone could help.

Im showing all the drives inside Stack in console:

```
public void ShowDrives()
    { 
        foreach (FileSystemInfo f in stack)
            Console.WriteLine(f);
    }

Output:
C:\
E:\
```

And now, when i press Left Arrow Key, I call another method, which shows the directories inside the particular drive, and write this data into the same stack

```
 public void ShowFiles(DirectoryInfo dif)
    {
            stack.Clear();
            foreach (FileSystemInfo f in dif.GetFileSystemInfos())
            {...} //show all files and directories and Write all inside the stack
     }
```

But my previous output for drives stays in console, i need to remove it somehow, and display new data of the stack.

```
Output:
C:\
E:\
C:\file1.doc
C:\folder
 etc...
```

And I need to get only

```
C:\file1.doc
C:\folder
 etc...
```

It's not allowed to use `Console.Clear()`
I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: If it's not allowed to use a clear method are you actually looking for a way to move the cursor about the screen?

Comment: Yes, i can move cursor position, but i need to delete previous output

Comment: @GyuzalRakhmayeva I've reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to completely clear the console?

```
Console.Clear();
```

...or are you looking to only overwrite certain lines?

Comment: Certain lines, i mean i need to display new content of Stack, im not allowed to use Console.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

You may move the cursor to the necessary line with `Console.SetCursorPosition` and simply overwrite the contents of that line with `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`.

However you should remember, if the number of lines of the previous output is greater, or some of the former output lines are longer than the corresponding lines of the later, you may have the previous output left....

The only thing I may suggest is to remember all those lengths and overwrite such garbage with spaces:

```
string oldoutput = "123";
Console.Write(oldoutput);
Console.ReadLine();

string newoutput = "!";
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
Console.Write(newoutput);

int delta = oldoutput.Length - newoutput.Length;
if (delta > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < delta; i++)
        Console.Write(" ");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```